# Fluentd parse different logs format

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, fluentd

I need to parse different logs from a single file with different regex expressions using fluentd; the problem is I don't know how to put 3 regexs in one parse section. can anybody tell me how can I do it? I need to add another regex in a multiline format.

this is my conf file for one log:

```
   @type tail
   path /opt/td-agent/dev/events.log
   pos_file /opt/td-agent/dev/events.log.pos
   tag events
   <parse>
   @type multiline
   format_firstline /^\d+/
   format1 /^(?<msg_id>(\d+)) (?<time>(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})) UTC (?<severity>(\S+\b)): (?<subject>(\S+\b)) \#(?<sub_id>(\S+)) (?<router_name>(\b\S+\b)) (?<ip_addr>(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}))\n
   format2 /(?<message>(.|s)*)/
   </parse>
   </source>
```

Comment: How about combining all three with OR | operator e.g. `re1|re2|re3`? https://regex101.com/r/wmFzmu/1

Comment: It doesn't work with multiline type, it only parses the first line

Comment: Please add the three logs samples in your questions that you're trying to parse. I'll try to test those on my side.